# Directory Index in Laravel htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4

I have a route

```
  Route::get('/site/{slug}', 'HomeController@showPage');
```

And my controller is:

```
  public function showPage($slug){
  //Find an instance of your Page model
  $page = Pages::all();
  $pages = Pages::where("slug", "=", $slug)->first();
  return View::make('layouts.frontend')->with('pages', $pages)->with('page',$page);
}
```

But i have to manually go to localhost:8000/site/home to get the site to display, so I wondered of Directory Index can be used and how ? So that when i navigate to localhost:8000 it just shows the home page straight away then the navigation will take care of the rest of the website.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need htaccess?

Otherwise you could do just

```
Route::any('/', function(){
  return Redirect::to('site/home');
});
```

Comment: Tried that but i have built a CMS thats located at Route::get('/cms', 'AdminController@login');

So that will not work, any other suggestions?

Comment: Route::any('/', function(){
       return Redirect::to('site/home');
      });

Worked a treat

Answer (score 0):

Create a route to / and redirect to your actual index from there.